# Using Apex or API, how to determine who has access to a Document Folder?

Tags: apex, api, files, document, folder

In Salesforce UI, I can assign access to Document Folders.

How can I determine who has access to a Document Folder with Apex or API? I thought I would find an object like "FolderMember" or similar, but no luck as of yet. Maybe I missed it?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only object that exposes this is the [DocumentFolder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_folder.htm) object, which is only in the Metadata API. Calling the Metadata API from Apex Code is non-trivial, but as long as you follow the rules for retrieving DocumentFolder, this should help you.

Comment: Thanks! I needed to use Metadata API to retrieve the [DocumentFolder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_folder.htm). It includes a nested type `sharedTo` with elements for the roles, groups, and portal roles the folder is shared with.